# Suppress messages from log file and console

Tags: graphics

I try to suppress messages such that

```
File: 2302.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<2302.eps>
```

from log file as well as the console .. since the eps files are imported via \includegraphics, a macro of graphicx package, i tried to load the package as

```
\usepackage[quiet]{graphicx}
```

However, in the log file a message displays saying that

```
preamble.tex:31: LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
The package graphicx has already been loaded with options: []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options [quiet]
```

The point is that i did not load the package previously, as i can be seen by the following lines:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\PackageInfo}[2]{} % Remove package information
\renewcommand{\@font@info}[1]{}  % Remove font information
\renewcommand{\@latex@info}[1]{} % Remove LaTeX information
\makeatother

\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[american,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\def\eng#1{\textlatin{#1}}
\newcommand{\sg}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\sa}{\selectlanguage{american}}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names,named]{xcolor}
\WarningFilter*{mdframed}{You got a bad break}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Text page}
\usepackage[usetwoside]{mdframed}
\usepackage[quiet]{graphicx}  <==== THE PACKAGE IS LOADED HERE
```

My question is what happens and how i can suppress these messages? Thanks a lot !

Comment: `epsfig` (which should not be used in any document written this century) is just a thin wrapper around `graphicx` and loads that package.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the terminal output from your test file you see:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kerkis/kerkis.sty  
***********************************************
******** Loading The Kerkis FontFamily ********
********** Department of Mathematics **********
*********** University of the Aegean **********
***********************************************)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/epsfig.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))))
```

Note the position of the `()` The `(` denoting the opening of `epsfig.sty` is not closed with a matching `)` until after `graphicx.sty`, `graphics.sty`, `trig.sty`, `graphics.cfg` and `pdftex.def` have been read, showing that all those files are input directly or indirectly by `epsfig`.

You could load `graphicx` with options before `epsfig` but better is not to load `epsfig` at all, it was just written (in 1994) to help convert documents that were old *then* to the "new" latex2e graphics system. It is just a thin wrapper around the `graphicx` package emulating the LaTeX2.09 style `epsfig` file that was popular before LaTeX2e was produced.

Comment: Therefore I need to load ONLY the graphics package with the appropriate options and NOT the epsfig .. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: if you were actually using epsfig, so had commands `\epsfig{file=..}` they would need changing to `\includegraphics{...}` (which is all the definition of `\epsfig` is) If you were not using the package then simply not loading it is of course a good idea.